# Google Chrome failing on youtube

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube

So my issue is that only youtube site is having problem, its completly messed up as in no layout and cant load any videos whatsoever, i tried clearing cache among other solutions around teh internet but without avail, i know the problem aint from the site since i can access it from the other PC and it was working fine earlier on the one thats having problems now, i inspected the page and got these

```
GET https://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-core-webp-vflOXuTs6.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):13
GET https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/QxvDVqZdqRU/hqdefault.jpg net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):554
GET https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/hafj2CLubHE/mqdefault.jpg net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):600
GET https://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-home-c4-webp-vflIvxUPq.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):14
GET https://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-pageframe-webp-vflgztbLD.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):22
GET https://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-guide-webp-vfl_uF6sZ.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):23
GET https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/YuFs_aHhm44/mqdefault.jpg net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):648
GET https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/SDlTZofXa7c/mqdefault.jpg net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):696
GET https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-scheduler-vflKNUgKf.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):9
GET https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/spf-vflXayUFd.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):4263
GET https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-en_US-vflHVohGO/base.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):4264
Uncaught ReferenceError: spf is not defined (index):4265
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):4270
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):4303
GET https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):31
```

Anyone has any ideas of what the problem might be? as im in a huge need of accessing the goddam youtube for tutorials

Comment: The [YouTube Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/youtube) is screaming with people having problems. There are others having Chrome issues with HTTPS, too. It sounds like it could be a WebKit problem. Try a manual update of Chrome by visiting the site. Don't expect Chrome update t work because that's sent with SSL/TLS, too.

Comment: Windows 8.1 on this one, it doesnt work on any other brownser on this pc, i can ping the site with tracert, wireless conection didnt had any problems (started messing up after installing a game League of Legends) but i dont know how that can affect it...the other PC is windows 7 the problem is only on youtube site